# Problem with bibliography section header and font size

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using the elsarticle document type.

```
 \documentclass[preprint,1p,times]{elsarticle}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{thebibliography}{9}
 \bibitem{myref2003} 2003, my reference
 \end{thebibliography}
 \end{document}
```

I have two problems:
1) the bibliography appears without the section header "References"
2) The bibliography appears with font of the same size as footnotes

This has not always been the case. Initially things were working ok. At some point I tried to import the natbib package and the problem started. I have since removed the natbib package and deleted all temporary files, but the problem remains.

How can I fix or debug the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "issues" seem to originate from the latest version of `elsarticle`. At some time, your LaTeX distribution may have updated `elsarticle` to the faulty version, which would explain why the issues weren't there in the beginning.

## Missing section header

The issue has already been discussed [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/dXNOt1Hn4Gs). I quote the answer:

> elsarticle.cls ends with
>
> ```
>    \@ifpackageloaded{amsrefs}%
>        {}
>        {\let\bibsection\relax%
>        \AtBeginDocument{\def\cites@b#1#2,#3{%
>            \begingroup[%
>                \toks@{\InnerCite{#2}#1}%
>                \ifx\@empty#3\@xp\@gobble\fi
>                \cites@c#3%
>    }}}
> ```
>
> This is what makes the heading disappear, since natbib redefines
>   the thebibliography environment to start with \bibsection, which
>   is responsible for the typesetting of the bibliography heading.
>
> I don't know if this is a design decision or simply a mistake.
>   To recover natbib's definition of \bibsection you may try to
>   write
>
> ```
>    \newcommand\bibsection{%
>        \section*{\bibname\markright{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}}}
> ```
>
> in the preamble of your document. It's \newcommand and not
>   \renewcommand as one might expect.

The link above also points to an updated version of `elsarticle` from 2011, which also fixes the issue: http://download.river-valley.com/elsarticle/elsarticle-v1.21-ELS.zip.

However, although the updated package *seems* to originate from the official `elsarticle` developers, it hasn't been uploaded to the [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/), or MikTeX package manager for example, which still use the faulty 2009 version.

## Bibliography font size

Not sure if it's an issue. `elsarticle` redefines the bibliography font size for options `1p`, `3p` and `5p`:

```
\global\let\bibfont=\footnotesize
```

You can change it by adding to your preamble:

```
\let\bibfont\small
```

or whatever font size you want.

## Fixed example

```
\documentclass[preprint,1p,times]{elsarticle}
\newcommand\bibsection{\section*{\bibname\markright{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}}}
\let\bibfont\small
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{myref2003} 2003, my reference
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: Fixed bibliography 1]

or, with the updated `elsarticle` class (to make it quick, you can extract the `elsarticle.cls` file and add it in the same folder as your `.tex` file):

```
\documentclass[preprint,1p,times]{elsarticle}
\let\bibfont\small
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{myref2003} 2003, my reference
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fixed bibliography 2]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I work on different machines (windows, Linux, iPad) so fixing the elsarticle class is not practical. Plus I am not sure what version will the editor use. Fixing the file locally works just fine. Thanks.