# Cannot change natbib bibliography font size [memoir class]

Tags: bibliographies, memoir, natbib, fontsize

I am using the ucbthesis class (which is based off the memoir class) with natbib and cannot find any way to change the size of the font in my references (in the bib, not the textual citations). It is too small and I need it to be the same size as the the main text. I have already tried adding [\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalsize}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383447/format-natbib-font-style) to my preamble, but that throws an error saying \bibfont is undefined. I have also tried [\let\bibfont\normalsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376023/problem-with-bibliography-section-header-and-font-size), which has no effect.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[oldfontcommands]{ucbthesis}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Prexy Salaam}
\section{Faceplate Marginalia}
Invasive brag \cite{waveshaping}.
\HUGE{Why can't I change the font size of the references?}

\bibliographystyle{natbib}
\HUGE{\bibliography{references}}

\end{document}
```

And references.bib is:

```
@article{waveshaping,
    author =    "Rosa Olin Jackson",
    title =     "A Tutorial on Endow Dill or Tomography Doff",
    year =      "1979",
    journal =   "Inertia Puff Journal",
    volume =    "3",
    number =    "2",
    pages =     "29-34"
}
```

The [ucbthesis class is available here.](https://github.com/pimentel/ucbthesis-phd)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Sorry, your question is not clear ... Which font do you mean? The font for the citing in your text or the font used in the bibliography?  Can you please add an screenshot and mark there what you want to change? And where does `\bibliographystyle{natbib}` comes from? Or do you mean `plainnat` or ...

Comment: Off-topic: Writing `\HUGE{Why can't I change the font size of the references?}` is almost certainly incorrect. It should be `{\HUGE Why can't I change the font size of the references?}`. `\Huge` is a switch, i.e., it doesn't take an argument. Incidentally, is there a bibliography *style* (not package) called `natbib`.? For sure, the `natbib` package itself does not provide a bibliography style file called `natbib.bst`.

Comment: By the way, the example you posted does change the font size in use in the bibliography to `\HUGE`. That's what you want to achieve, right? If you want `\normalsize` instead, just issue the directive `\normalsize` immediately before `\bibliography`.

Comment: Why is this labelled memoir (in the title) when it is not related to the question?

Comment: Thank you, Kurt and Mico. Your responses helped me figure out a solution. I did mean the text in the bibliography.

I have both a natbib.sty and natbib.bst file. I assume they came from one of the journals I have been working with. I didn't realize the .sty was the package while the .bst is a style? I still find the terminology confusing. In any case, my natbib.sty sets the bibliography environment font size to 7. I just changed it to 12.

Also, thank you for the note about switches, Mico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within my natbib.sty file I had the following block:

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
 \bibsection
 \vspace{1\p@}\parindent \z@\bibpreamble\bibfont\list
   {\@biblabel{\arabic{NAT@ctr}}}{\@bibsetup{#1}%
    \setcounter{NAT@ctr}{0}}%
    \ifNAT@openbib
      \renewcommand\newblock{\par}
    \else
      \renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}%
    \fi
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
    \let\citeN\cite \let\shortcite\cite
    \let\citeasnoun\cite\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont
 }{\def\@noitemerr{%
  \PackageWarning{natbib}
     {Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist\vskip-\lastskip}
```

I changed the `\fontsize{7}{9}` to `\fontsize{12}{14}`.